# Как из layout вызвать?

Tags: android

При вызове AlertBuild пишет ошибку: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Код такой:

```
public class LayoutImageView extends LinearLayout {

@BindView(R.id.text)
TextView textView;
@BindView(R.id.image)
ImageView view;
@BindView(R.id.image_text_layout)
LinearLayout imageTextLayout;
private Drawable draweble = null;

public LayoutImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.image_view, this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.post_text));
    final LinearLayout layout = this;
    imageTextLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext().getApplicationContext());
            View mView = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_imageview, layout);
            PhotoView photoView = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            photoView.setImageDrawable(draweble);
            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Как сделать, чтобы нормально работало. Пробовал писать AlertDialog.Builder через активи, но его красным подчеркивает пишет: is not an enclosing class

Answer (score 0):

Используйте вызываемое активити в качестве контекста:

Вместо:

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext().getApplicationContext());
```

Так:

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Comment: Только не `LayoutImageView.this` - это ж виджет. Просто убрать `getApplicationContext()`. И при создании самого `LayoutImageView` передавать ему в конструктор активити, а не апп-контекст.

Comment: хм. Я невежда))

Comment: Я тоже думал об этом. Думал, можно было легче сделать(